# save PDF contents to my sql table

Tags: java, mysql, file, pdf

I want to store the pdf file in mysql database. The general form of the pdf is:

```
HEADING
SOME PARAGRAPHA OF DATA


HEADING 
SOME PARAGRAPH OF DATA
and so on.
```

So there will be two columns in my sql database viz : Heading and Data.
I want to store the headings and their respective data in the table.
Now i have tried reading the file using iText but I am not able to segment the data and then store them according to my database. Can you please help me in parsing ans saving the data in the tables.

Comment: This is a very generic question. I think, you need to share your `iText` code and ask as which portion not working. Also, it doesn't look anything to do with db if you can do iText processing successfully.

Comment: ***WHY*** aren't you able to "segment the data and then store them"? Please review ["how to ask a question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise this question accordingly with relevant code showing what you have tried and telling, in detail, why it didn't work.

Comment: I am struggling with the approach. m not that gifted in programming so still figuring out how to identify and segment the data according to my needs. I have extracted the entire data in a single string variable. But from then i m stuck as to what approach should i use. And i am new to itext and pdf file handling so dont know how to access the tags of a pdf file and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the content of the document in a String and parse it following the assumed structure. An example of extracting the content can be found [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15#576-parsinghelloworld.java).